# Expand $z$ in power series of $w$ for each branches, where $w=2z+z^2$.

Tags: complex-analysis, complex-numbers

Define
$$w=z^2+2z$$
Just heuristics:
$$z=\pm\exp\left(\frac{\log(w+1)}2\right)-1$$
If we expand $\log (1+w)$ into a power series for $|w|<1$, and further exponentiate it, how would the series look like?

Answer (score 0):

I assume we have to expand around $0$.

Consider the given dependence as an algebraic equation of second degree in $z$ with parameter $w$,
$$
z^2 + 2z - w =0\ ,$$
then the (two branches) solution is
$$
\begin{aligned}
z_{1,2}=z_{1,2}(w)
&=-1\pm\sqrt{1+w}
=-1\pm\sum_{n\ge 0}\binom{1/2}n w^n
\\
z_1=z_1(w)
&=\sum_{n\ge 1}\binom{1/2}n w^n
\\
z_2=z_2(w)
&=
-2-\sum_{n\ge 1}\binom{1/2}n w^n
\ .
\end{aligned}
$$

---

Computer check modulo $O(w^8)$, here [sage](http://www.sagemath.org):

```
sage: R.<w> = PowerSeriesRing( QQ, default_prec=8 )
sage: z1 = -1 + sqrt(1+w)
sage: z2 = -1 - sqrt(1+w)
sage: z1
1/2*w - 1/8*w^2 + 1/16*w^3 - 5/128*w^4 + 7/256*w^5 - 21/1024*w^6 + 33/2048*w^7 + O(w^8)
sage: z2
-2 - 1/2*w + 1/8*w^2 - 1/16*w^3 + 5/128*w^4 - 7/256*w^5 + 21/1024*w^6 - 33/2048*w^7 + O(w^8)

sage: z1^2 + 2*z1
w + O(w^8)
sage: z2^2 + 2*z2
w + O(w^8)
```